# Implementing and using a generic, abstract interface in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface, abstract

I am tasked with creating a predicate interface and implementing a number of classes that implements that interface. For example, a class called `StartsWith` is to be generic and needs to have a constructor that accepts any object that is a subclass of `CharSequence`.

Here is what I currently have:

##### Predicate.java

```
package predicates;

interface Predicate<T> {
    public char StartsWith(T obj);
}
```

##### StartsWith.java

```
package predicates;

public class StartsWith<T extends CharSequence> implements Predicate<T> {

    @Override
    public char StartsWith(T obj) {
        
        return 'a';
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

An example of creating a StartsWith object must look like the following:

```
StartsWith<String> predicate = new StartsWith<String>("aB");
```

When I try to instantiate an object like this I am immediately met with an error that says the arguments do not match and for me to provide no arguments in order to make it right, however, it MUST be called this way.

I am confused as to what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Note: you should follow the Java Naming Conventions. Method names should be written in camelCase, so it starts with lowercase. The method `StartsWith` should be `startsWith`.

Comment: And your `StartsWith` class should probably override `Predicate`'s `test` method.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
public char StartsWith(T obj) {
    //....
```

... is a *method* declaration, **not** a constructor. I'd in fact call it a "pseudo" constructor since it has the same name as a class.  Constructors don't have a return type, not void, not anything.

and here:

```
StartsWith<String> predicate = new StartsWith<String>("aB");
```

You call it as if it were a constructor, which *again*, it is most definitely not.

So,...

- Don't give your methods the same names as constructors
- Learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

So, for example:

```java
public class FooPredicate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StartsWith<String> predicate = new StartsWith<String>();
        
        System.out.println(predicate.startsWithMethod("abc"));
    } 
}
```

```
interface Predicate<T> {
    public char startsWithMethod(T obj);
}
```

```
class StartsWith<T extends CharSequence> implements Predicate<T> {

    @Override
    public char startsWithMethod(T obj) {
        
        return 'a';
        
    }
}
```